# How do I install python-ldap on ActivePython 2.6?

Tags: ldap, python-2.6

I'm using ActivePython to run OSQA (To create a site just like this one!)

One thing we really need is LDAP authentication, which was provided via a patch.
However, I need ldap installed on this version of python and when I try easy_install or pip it fails to install python-ldap

Is there an easy way to install python-ldap on ActivePython 2.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing python-ldap via. easy_install results in an error, so one must [download the source](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap/2.3.13)
After extracting the file change your setup.cfg to replace the following three lines:

```
libs = ldap_r lber sasl2 ssl crypto  
library_dirs = /usr/local/openldap-2.3/lib  
include_dirs = /usr/local/openldap-2.3/include /usr/include/sasl
```

with the next three lines:

```
libs = ldap lber sasl2 ssl crypto  
library_dirs = /usr/local/lib  
include_dirs = /usr/local/include /usr/include/sasl
```

Then run

```
ActivePython setup.py build
sudo ActivePython setup.py install
```

And your done.